# Filtrar elemento a partir de taxonomia no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomia

Na página de artigo (single.php) do meu tema tenho o seguinte código que filtra um div fazendo com que ela apareça somente em páginas de determinada categoria:

```
<?php $categoria_post = the_category_id($categoria_post);
if ($categoria_post == 760) : ?>
<div>
...
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Eu preciso filtrar uma div de forma semelhante, porém a partir do slug de uma taxonomia (series_especiais), ignorando o id.

Algo semelhante, mas filtrado somente pelo slug:

**EDITADO**

Forma que essa taxonomia customizada foi criada:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_tax' );

function create_post_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'series_especiais',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Séries Especiais' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'series_especiais','with_front' => true ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem o *ID* da categoria em `$categoria_post`, você pode usar o método [`get_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category)

```
$categoria = get_category($categoria_post)
```

e acessá-lo com

```
$categoria['slug']
```

Só lembrando que [`the_category_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category_id/) é um método deprecado, portanto, vale reavaliar o seu código. Como você está no `single.php`, faz mais sentido utilizar o método [`wp_get_post_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/). Usando [`the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID), é tão simples quanto

```
$cats = wp_get_post_categories(the_ID());
```

`$cats` é um *array* (mesmo que o post tenha uma só categoria). A partir daí, é buscar o *slug* e fazer o seu filtro.

Comment: O problema é exatamente esse, a taxonomia não possui um id, é só um aglutinador de 2 sub-categorias.
Eu precisaria filtrar essa taxonomia sem id somente pelo slug.

Comment: Todas as taxonomias (e categorias) possuem obrigatoriamente um ID. Minha resposta foi baseada no seu código, a partir do ID que você já alega ter.

Comment: Obrigado, Caio.
Não sabia.
Existe alguma forma de filtrar somente pelo slug ignorando a id?

Comment: Você quer capturar o `slug` da categoria do post, é isso?

Comment: O slug eu tenho, não tenho é o id e preciso filtrar por essa taxonomia.
Só tenho o slug dele.

Comment: Então eu não entendi nada. Sugiro que reformule a sua pergunta.

Comment: Talvez o segundo edit com a forma que essa taxonomia ajude a compreensão.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi solucionado por um usuário do fórum de wordpress em inglês [(https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46066/tim-malone)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46066/tim-malone).

A solução foi a seguinte:

```
<?php
$especiais = get_the_terms( $post, 'series_especiais' );
if( is_array( $especiais ) && count( $especiais ) ) : ?>
```

Link original da solução:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231647/filtering-elements-by-taxonomy-slug/